# Grease pencil Line-art modifier generates extra lines

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I used grease pencil's line-art modifier. But it generates extra lines outside, at the edge, and inside the camera view.
[image]

Besides, they are very flickering and unpleasing. Is there a way to fix this problem, or is it a bug?

[The file](https://easyupload.io/1akqt8) and settings
[image]

Comment: Hello, please add the settings of your line art modifier

Comment: Hello. I added a picture of the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off *Show in front* in *Object Properties* menu, for the line art and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this setting. Also, make sure you just select the objects you want the lines on.  Sorry I could not see the settings you are using.

Comment: Thank you. But I could fix it by turning off Line-art's "show in front" in the object properties menu.